# Is there a way to calculate a dynamic column in SQL based on multiple other columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to determine if something is possible to do in SQL where I am creating a view for users and I need to create a column that would state whether or not a line number is "Open" or "Closed". The trouble is that the process to determine that value is based on multiple factors/values of other columns from the source table. Take a look at some data that the view currently generates.

```
Line #  Req_Qty  Rej_Qty     Adj_Qty    Alt_Qty Shipped Cxl     Rec     Conf
Line 1  71.00    0.00        100.00     0.00    100.00  0.00    100.00  100.00  
Line 2  23.00    0.00        0.00       0.00    23.00   0.00    0.00    0.00    
Line 3  11.00    0.00        10.00      0.00    10.00   0.00    0.00    0.00    
Line 4  12.00    12.00       0.00       0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    
Line 5  0.00     0.00        0.00       20.00   20.00   0.00    0.00    0.00
```

In the table above the way the determination is made is as follows:
If there is any value > 0 in Adj_Qty, then the Adj_Qty(Adjusted Qty) effectively becomes the Req_Qty(Requested Qty). If both the Req_Qty and the Adj_Qty are 0  and the Alt_Qty >0, then that now becomes the real Req_ Quantity. So basically, my first comparison is Adj->Req->Alt. Whatever that quantity is would then be reduced by the Rej_Qty(Rejected) or the Cxl_Qty(Cancelled) which results in a balance.

Finally, if the quantity in either the Rec or Conf columns matches that balance, then the line # is closed. So, for the table, Lines 1 and 4 would be closed, 2, 3, and 5 would be open. Is there any way to create a field/column in SQL that would be able to assign "Open" or "Closed" based on that type of logic?

Comment: Break a goal into pieces that you can achieve. Focus on the logic to compute your "quantity" (for lack of a better word - teminology is important in requirements). Once you have that correct, the additional logic seems to be a piece of cake. Seems like the first step is exactly opposite of what you write - check for zero values in Req_Qty and Adj_Qty leads to using Alt_Qty. And once you get this working, put the logic into a view or a computed column so you can isolate your business logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `CASE` clause to compute the balance and the status in the view. For example:

```
create view v as
select *,
  case when (
    case when adj_qty > 0 then adj_qty
         when req_qty > 0 then req_qty
         when alt_qty > 0 then alt_qty
         else 0.0
    end
    - rej_qty
    - cxl_qty
    ) in (rec, conf) then 'closed'
       else 'open' end as status
from t
```

I probably didn't understand all the details of your specific logic but this query should be pretty close to what you need. Tweak as needed.

Comment: This was very close to what I needed, thank you! Only adjustment I had to make was change the "IN" statement into two <= statements, now i'm getting the result I hoped for. Thank you so very much!